# How to close dropdown when click outside anywhere on screen in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am adding a "open" class on click to open the dropdown menu. I am isOpen as boolean to toggle open and close on click. its working fine.PROBLEM is dropdown menu does not close when I click outside (anywhere on screen).it only open and close when click on button. 
here is the code:

```
********************
      HTML
********************

<div class="btn-group dropdown" [class.open]="isOpen">
   <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle area-dropdown" (click)="onDropdownToggle()">
   <span class="eo-select-label ellipsis"> Select area size</span>
   <span aria-hidden="true" class="caret glyphicon></span>
   </button>
 <ul class="eo-dropdown-menu">
    <li class="li-employee-number-selector"> 5 - 50 Square meters </li>
    <li class="li-employee-number-selector"> 51 - 100 Square meters </li>
 </ul>
</div>

********************
     Component.ts
********************

    export class SellerFactoryProfileComponent implements OnInit {
      isOpen: boolean;

    constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      onDropdownToggle() {
        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To listen to a window event (click for example) you must add event listener method in your component decorated with @HostListener('document:click') decorator.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your @Component

```
selector: '<app-name>',
host: {
    '(document:click)': 'functionClick($event)',
  }

functionClick {
    this.open = false 
}
```